# cant able to get proper responses in dofilter method?

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, servlets, servlet-filters

I have defined servlet filter implementation in spring boot application. I could get only 200 response for all calls. How to get the appropriate response in dofilter method?

```
 public void doFilter(ServletRequest request, ServletResponse response, FilterChain chain)
            throws IOException, ServletException {
        doFilterFunction.requestFunction(request, response, chain);
    }


    public void requestFunction(ServletRequest request, ServletResponse response, FilterChain chain,String x_internal_key, String session, String user, String urlPat) throws IOException, ServletException {
                    chain.doFilter(request, response);
}
```

Comment: Post your code. From question its very difficult to understand the issue

Comment: The above code snippet has been updated with my code. I had simply used the the do filter function code.From this how can i alter to get response from the controller? Thanks in advance for your effort.

Answer (score 0):

I had removed try catch block to get the entire responses from servlet.Its working fine.